# Does the total Probability rule hold when the partition is of the event $B$ rather than of the entire sample space?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am wondering whether $$\mathbb{P}[B]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B \cap A_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B \mid A_i\right] \mathbb{P}\left[A_i\right]
 $$  holds when the $A_i$ are partitions of the event $B$ rather than of the entire sample space. I have learnt the Total Probability rule in the following form:

> let $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be a partition of the sample space $\Omega$. Then, the Total Probability Rule for any event $B$ is
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[B]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B \cap A_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B \mid A_i\right] \mathbb{P}\left[A_i\right]
> $$

I was wondering whether the partition could be any partition of the event $B$, rather than of the entire sample space. This certainly seems intuitively correct, as the partitions aggregately cover all of the sample points in $B$, but when they are scaled down; so we just scale these back up. However, the fact that I have not seen such a rule presented for a partition of $B$ but rather a partition of the entire sample space has led me to feel that perhaps this equality doesn't hold when we have merely a partition of $B$. So can the partition in the total Probability rule be of $B$ rather than of the entire sample space and still have the equation which it posits be rendered correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true and you can prove it.
if $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are partitions of the event $B \subset \Omega$ which means that $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{A_i}$, we can take one more event, $A_{n+1} = \Omega\setminus B$.
It easy to see that $\mathbb{P}[B \cap A_{n+1}] = 0$, and that $A_1, \ldots, A_{n+1}$ are a partition of $\Omega$.

Now all is left to do is to use the **Total Probability rule** as you mentioned.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[B] =& \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\left[B \cap A_i\right] =\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\left[B \cap A_i\right] + \underbrace{\mathbb{P}[B \cap A_{n+1}]}_{0}= \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left[B \mid A_i\right] \mathbb{P}\left[A_i\right]
\end{align}